# sorting an array to make it a circular one

Tags: arrays, sorting

I have an array, and I can exchange only ith and i+1th element. How can I sort this array into a circular one using minimum number of exchange operations?

For example my array is:-

```
3 5 4 2 1
```

Then exchanging 2nd and 3rd I get

```
3 4 5 2 1
```

And then exchanging 4th and 5th I get

```
3 4 5 1 2
```

which is the required sorted circular array in 2 exchanges.

Another example

```
4 3 5 1 2
```

Here just one exchange of 1st and 2nd gives me `3 4 5 1 2`

What algorithm should I use to achieve this?

Comment: what algo/approach have you tried? do you have at least a brute force algorithm?

Comment: also, can you exchange the first and last elements (= is that rule also circular)?

Comment: nope...only ith nd i+1th exchnge is allowed...i was trying to make a hash of the locations of the elements and thn checking whether they should be moved right or left..but that didnt work out quiet well

Answer (score 1):

You can use for loop with a temp variable then sort it all array elements , but for loop should be increment by 2 .

```
len=array[(array.length)];
for (i=1 ; i<len - 1 ; i=i+2 ){
    temp=array[i];
    array[i]=array[i+1];
    array[i+1]=temp;    
}
temp=array[0];
array[o]=array[len];
array[len]=temp;
```

this simple algorithm will work in java and sorts array perfectly as you required.

Comment: how will this technique guarantee minimum number of swaps...the number of swaps required here will always be n/2 atleast